# Attain insertOneWriteOpResult object after operation

Tags: node.js, mongodb

https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Collection.html#~insertOneWriteOpResult

How do I attain the `insertOneWriteOpResult` after performing an `insertOne` operation?

```
var result =
    yield users.insertOne({
        lol: 'lol'
    });
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

I only seem to get the object `{"ok":1,"n":1}` and not the list specified in the documentation.

Comment: What happens if you console.log(result) without JSON.stringify?

Comment: @simon-p-r Oh well o well o well, there we have it, it spits out everything now. Why would that be?

Comment: It can't be stringified due to values inside results object.  Can you accept my answer?

Comment: @simon-p-r Yes I can, post and I'll accept :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Result object may contain values that cannot be stringified, any values that cannot be stringified are stripped from object when you try to print them to console.